# How to declare identifier JSON in a C++ file?

Tags: c++, json, macos, compiler-errors, terminal

I got a c++ Project that correctly compiles on Windows.
Now I try to run it on my Mac.

I changed all paths to my Mac paths.
After "make" command I get this error message:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'Json'
Json::Reader reader;
```

Of course I included my header file containing `#include <json.h>`

Are there any necessary elements I missed?

Thanks for any ideas!!

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a wrong linking of `json_lib`

Reinstalled and problem got solved.